# Send email with wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Hi i am trying to send email in a wpf app but i get stuck;
i show my xaml code

```
 <Grid>
    <Button     Style="{DynamicResource ShowcaseRedBtn}"  CommandParameter="test@ygmail.com" Tag="Send Email" Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,186,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" Click="button1_Click" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92,70,0,0" Name="txtSubject" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" />
    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True"   Height="159" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92,121,0,0" Name="txtBody" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" />
</Grid>
```

and here in the code behind :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        if (btn == null)
            return;
        string url = btn.CommandParameter as string;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) 
            return;
        try
        {
            // here i wish set the parameters of email in this way 
            // 1. mailto = url;
            // 2. subject = txtSubject.Text;
            // 3. body = txtBody.Text;
            Process.Start("mailto:test@gmail.com?subject=Software&body=test ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

my purpose is set the parameters of the email binding the data from the form :
                 // 1. mailto = url;
                // 2. subject = txtSubject.Text;
                // 3. body = txtBody.Text;

Do you have any idea how work out this step?

Thanks so much for your attention.

Cheers

Comment: A Process.Start() with a "mailto:" URL will open the user mail client with a new pre-filled message. Is that what you want ? Or do you want to really send the mail when the button is pressed ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can send mail directly using the System.Net.MailMessage class. Look at the following example from the MSDN documentation for this class:

```
public static void CreateTimeoutTestMessage(string server)
        {
            string to = "jane@contoso.com";
            string from = "ben@contoso.com";
            string subject = "Using the new SMTP client.";
            string body = @"Using this new feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
            Console.WriteLine("Changing time out from {0} to 100.", client.Timeout);
            client.Timeout = 100;
            // Credentials are necessary if the server requires the client 
            // to authenticate before it will send e-mail on the client's behalf.
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

      try {
              client.Send(message);
            }  
            catch (Exception ex) {
              Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateTimeoutTestMessage(): {0}", 
                    ex.ToString() );              
          }
        }
```

Comment: What would you pass as "server"? e.g., if you wanted to send via your gmail account?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, Server is  webmail.yourwebsite.com

Comment: My website? I don't want to tie a certain website to sending email and don't understand why that would be a logical thing to do, either...

Comment: You have to control the server that's sending all your messages - imagine if anyone and everyone could use Google's email infrastructure for personal use.  The traffic would be horrendous.

Answer (score 3):

I have posted a similar and much simpler answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020377/link-to-open-new-email-message-in-default-e-mail-handler-in-wpf-application/29799970#29799970)

but for the emphasis

```html
<Button Content="Send Email" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
      <ei:LaunchUriOrFileAction Path="mailto:example@stackoverflow.com?subject=SubjectExample" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants: your approach opens a mail window from the default mail client. OP wants to send an email from within the application, without even having a mail client.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using codebehind, you don't need binding - although it's not very good pattern, it will of course work.

Why don't you just name your textboxes (urlTextBox, subjectTextBox, etc.) and use these names in the button click event?

```
        Process.Start(string.Format("mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body={2}", urlTextBox.Text, subjectTextBox.Text, ... ));
```

Of course this might easily fail, if user inputs invalid values.

Using bindings is another way to go, but in this simple case I consider it overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Just adjusting Tims answer for Google accounts as some people were inquiring

```
public static void CreateTimeoutTestMessage()
        {
            string to = "to address";
            string from = "from address";
            string subject = "Using the new SMTP client.";
            string body = @"Using this new feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);

            var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("@gmail.com", "secretPassword"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };

            try
            {
                client.Send(message);
                Debug.WriteLine("Sent");
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
```