# Link to Open New Email Message in Default E-mail Handler in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, email

My goal is basic: Have a label/texblock what-have-you on a WPF form that is stylized to look like a link. When clicked, the control should open a new e-mail composition window in the user's default e-mail app. The code to actually open the new e-mail window seems trivial:

```
Process.Start("mailto:example@stackoverflow.com?subject=SubjectExample&body=BodyExample ");
```

However I'm having trouble with two pieces:

1. Binding the "new message open" action to a label click event.
2. Stylizing the label so that it looks exactly like a default WPF hyperlink.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want the style to be like a hyperlink, why not just use one directly?

```
<TextBlock>           
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="mailto:example@stackoverflow.com?subject=SubjectExample&amp;body=BodyExample" RequestNavigate="OnNavigate">
        Click here
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Then add:

```
private void OnNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I was under the impression the NavigateUri property wouldn't know how to handle a mailto, but that's evidently not the case.

Comment: What if the `Subject` or `Body` contains the string `&`?

Comment: I had to use `&body`instead of `&amp;body` and escaped Subject and Body with `Uri.EscapeDataString` (in the ViewModel). YMMV if you do this in XAML directly though.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this entirely in XAML
Use Expression interactions to call the link mentioned above.

First, import the following namespaces:

```xml
xmlns:i  = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Then, use them like the following:

```html
<Label Content="Send Email">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
      <ei:LaunchUriOrFileAction Path="mailto:example@stackoverflow.com" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Label>
```

Comment: Where are the namespaces you used?. what is `ei`?

Comment: Ensure you have Blend installed, or you'll run into issues with this. If it's missing, run this from Package Manager Console: `Install-Package Blend.Interctivity.WPF.v4.0`

Comment: I get error message "<i:Interaction.Triggers> does not exist in XML namespace xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity".

Answer (score 1):

anyone using .net core can use Reeds answer but with a small tweak

```
private void OnNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri) { UseShellExecute = true });
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

you can see the .net core teams chat about it being a breaking change here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30303