# Handling HyperlinkCoulumn Click Event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid, routed-events

I have a `DataGrid` that contains a list of people that have email addresses. What I would like is that when the user clicks on one of the email addresses in the column, a new email is composed in outlook ready for the user to send.

I am currently having issues however with programming the click event on the column, this is what I have so far;

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}">
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="OnHyperlinkClick" />
    </Style>
</DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
```

And then the click event;

```
private void OnHyperlinkClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

This however causes a crash, stating that it cannot locate the resource and then the users email address. How can I program the click so that it works correctly?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020377/link-to-open-new-email-message-in-default-e-mail-handler-in-wpf-application) for some guidance. Also the [DataGridHyperlinkColumn Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridhyperlinkcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) has an example of what you are trying to do